# how to implement ckeditor 3 javascript api in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, api, jsp, ckeditor

I have config.js file in ckeditor dir but for some reason my project's JSP page is not implementing the code form this js file.
Config.js file is laoding on the page.

WebContent/ckeditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.autoGrow_minHeight = 300;
    config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 400;
    config.baseFloatZIndex = 2000;
    config.blockedKeystrokes =
        [
            CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66 /*B*/,
            CKEDITOR.CTRL + 73 /*I*/,
            CKEDITOR.CTRL + 85 /*U*/
        ];
    config.bodyId = 'Anshul_contents_id';
    config.filebrowserWindowFeatures = 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=no';

};
```

WebContent/index.jsp

```
<lable>Description</lable>
<div>
     <textarea cols="50" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="7" />
</div>
<ckeditor:replace replace="editor1" basePath="ckeditor/" />
```

Comment: It seems you've written your own custom tag for that. Source code of tag is required to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was tricky is because the `Class ConfigurationHelper` have static methods. We can call them in a specific way.

Like calling 
static CKEditorConfig basic() function in ConfigurationHelper

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://ckeditor.com" prefix="ckeditor" %>

CKEditorConfig ckConfig = new CKEditorConfig();
ckConfig = ConfigurationHelper.basic();

<td>Description</td>
<td>
<textarea cols="50" id="description" name="description" rows="7"></textarea>
</td>

<ckeditor:replace replace="description" basePath="ckeditor/" config="<%=ckConfig %>"/>
```